Problems with Overleaf bibtex
According to the guidelines in link, on Overleaf, I can upload a ref.bib file that includes all the references I need and refer to this file using the following commands:

\bibliographystyle{amsalpha}  \bibliography{ref.bib}

My code has the following template:

\documentclass[16pt]{amsart} 
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\begin{document} 
... 
\bibliographystyle{amsalpha} 
\bibliography{ref.bib} 
\end{document}

I suppose these are all the set-up I need to finish, not like when using biblatex I need to import the package, add the source .bib file and then print the bibliography. Beside "\cite" command, I also have commands such as "{\cite[Definition 1]{1}}" as a header of a newly introduced definition. However, I was prompted the following errors when I compiled the code:

Latex error: Missing \begin{document} 
Undefined control sequence: \abx@aux@segm 
Undefined control sequence: \abx@aux@cite 

and beside the first error, the rest of the errors are either the second or the third error but in different lines in the "./output.aux" file. Could anyone explain what could cause these errors or point out what I possibly did wrong? Thank you.

Thank you for your help! After choosing "recompile from scratch", my code can be compiled without problems. Could you please move your comments to the answer so that I can mark your answer correct?

am I meant to delete a 'welcome' comment, leave it or delete and repeat?

welcome! ......

On Overleaf, you need to use the recompile from scratch option.
If you are not on Overleaf, you need to delete generated files (at least the .aux and probably any bibliography-related files such as .bbl).
The underlying issue is that you have previously compiled with Biblatex (and possibly run Biber). Biblatex writes commands to the .aux to read back on subsequent runs, but these are not known to BibTeX.
A couple more comments:

\bibliography{ref} is the standard syntax (without extension).
amsart has no 16pt option, so this does nothing.
amsart will load amsmath, so you needn't specify it unless you want to ensure it receives particular options or is loaded at a specific point in the preamble.

